# Jenkins CI - Deployment to an EC2 instance in APAC region from NA virginia

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins, regions

I have Jenkins build server in NA Virginia. All my Dev servers are in NA. We have spun up new Dev servers in APAC Singapore. I have set up Jenkins to deploy artifacts in Singapore over SSH using SSH plugin. This deploy is more time consuming then expected. Is there a better way to deploy code across different AWS regions?

Answer (score 3):

You could put a Jenkins build slave in the APAC region and run your deployment jobs on that slave, so that the artifacts you deploy are in APAC as soon as they are built.  Note that you'll still get some latency at the end of the build when logs and any archived artifacts are copied from the slave to the master, but at least this won't delay your deployment.

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds for details on setting up Jenkins slaves.

Comment: I tried setting up the slave. I am getting an error.. Check your .bashrc, .profile, and so on to make sure it is quiet.
The received junk text is as follows:
'true' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You'll need to tell us the method you are using to start the slave, plus other details such as the script you're using if applicable, if you want help.